# Spring Boot Application doesn't write data to MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I create a simple Spring Boot application. Running the app shows a JSON employee table in the browser, but when I check MySQL database with the command-line or MySQL Work-bench, a table employee table is generated, but no content.

Running the app from IntelliJ doesn't give me any error:

[image]

Take a look at my code on github:
[demo](https://github.com/LucasHartman/demo)

Comment: did you write the save method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only static data you are not using Jpa method for save that's why it's not saving in database table.

Comment: Thx for pointing me in the right direction. I found a create article giving a short and simple to understand example: https://javatechonline.com/saving-data-into-database-using-spring-boot-data-jpa-step-by-step-tutorial/